# Cannot write in logs folder even after correct permissions

Tags: laravel-5.5, permission-denied

I am getting the error `The stream or file "/opt/lampp/htdocs/project/storage/logs/laravel-date.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied`

I have tried setting the permissions as both `777` and `775`. I suddenly started getting this error. Here's the `ls -l` output of the project.

```
drwxrwxr-x 15 root   www-data  4096 Dec  2  2018 project
```

I am using XAMPP for my current development environment and not the native LAMPP stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I read through a comment in [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-framework-file-permission-security) and changed my directory permissions to `777` for `app` and `public` folders. `775` for `storage` and the rest is `664`. And it worked.